# How can i map array of objects and return specific properties from the objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with this format:

```
[
    {
        "team_key": "2611",
        "team_name": "Leicester",
        "team_badge": "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2611_leicester.png",
        "founded": "1884; 136 years ago (as Leicester Fosse FC)",
        "city": "Leicester"
    },
    {
        "team_key": "2612",
        "team_name": "Everton",
        "team_badge": "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2612_everton.png",
        "founded": "1878; 142 years ago",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
]
```

I want to map the array and return a new array with only specific parameters like "team_name" and "founded".

The new array should look like this:

```
 [
        {
            "team_name": "Leicester",
            "founded": "1884; 136 years ago (as Leicester Fosse FC)",
        },
        {
            "team_name": "Everton",
            "founded": "1878; 142 years ago",
        }
    ]
```

Comment: And what was the problem with what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the array?

```js
const data = [
    {
        "team_key": "2611",
        "team_name": "Leicester",
        "team_badge": "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2611_leicester.png",
        "founded": "1884; 136 years ago (as Leicester Fosse FC)",
        "city": "Leicester"
    },
    {
        "team_key": "2612",
        "team_name": "Everton",
        "team_badge": "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2612_everton.png",
        "founded": "1878; 142 years ago",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
]

console.log(
    // Destruct the object argument into desired keys
    // and return a new object from them.
    data.map(({ team_key, founded }) => ({ team_key, founded }))

)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your questing, let's assume, the initial array is x.

```
x = [
{
    "team_key": "2611",
    "team_name": "Leicester",
    "team_badge": "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2611_leicester.png",
    "founded": "1884; 136 years ago (as Leicester Fosse FC)",
    "city": "Leicester"
},
{
    "team_key": "2612",
    "team_name": "Everton",
    "team_badge": "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2612_everton.png",
    "founded": "1878; 142 years ago",
    "city": "Liverpool"
},
```

]

now you want to remove some items from that array-objects,

```
y = x.map ( v => {
    return {
        team_name: v.team_name,
        founded: v.founded
    }
})
```

more short hand answer :

```
y =  x.map(({ team_key, founded }) => ({ team_key, founded }))
```

now y is your new array.

if I understood the question wrong or you expect some other answer, please let me know by message or reply, will try best to solve it.